# Redefine latin letters slots for X2 font encoding

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic

My task is to typeset Ukrainian/English documents in LaTeX, getting searchable pdf output. The task is almost solved using `\fontenc[X2]` for Ukrainian language, switching to English via `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont`. The only problem: 52 English letters A-Z and a-z are valid also in X2, but they are treated as extended cyrillics; e.g. `A` is viewed as Æ. So, here is very probable error to forget to switch to T1 and get something like extended Cyrillic Æ instead of English A. I'm attempting to redefine slots 65-112 for X2 so that the error point could be easily found.  However, commands `\DeclareTextSymbol` and `\DeclareTextCommand` do not help; it seems that these commands declare new TeX control sequence associating it with the given slot, and it is not what I need.

So, the question: how (and is it whether possible) to redefine slots 65-112 for encoding X2 so that TeX produces something like error (or type some strange output) when English letter occurs while X2 is on?

Comment: You my prefer to use luatex and TU (Unicode) encoding so Latin ad Cyrillic both have "natural" slots. In pdftex you can not redefie ascii slots at the tex level, you could us a virtual font that put a blank or in those slots but you would have to do that sparately for every font used. Or use T2 rather than X2

Comment: @David Carlisle, thanks for reply. T2A was my first thought, but there is a problem with Ukrainian І (and small і) - it looks just like English I, but should have other code. In Windows 1251 codes of І/і are 178 and 179, but T2A put them in the same slots as English I/i, so generated pdf cannot correctly search for Ukrainian words with І/і. X2 generates correct pdf (despite that the codes for Ukrainian І/і are the same as T2A), but there aren't Latins at all.

Comment: @David, one more question in this topic. When I try to redefine `CYRAE` (it is in slot 65 and is output instead of English A), I expect to see other result for typing English A. However, result was the same - extended Cyrillic Æ. I tried to redefine `CYRAE` by several methods (`\newcommand`, `\DeclareTextSymbol` and something else) - unsuccefully. What way is for English A in X2 to become Æ? I was sure that it becomes control sequence `\CYRAE`, so try to do something with it.

Comment: you could use a latin i but set the acualtext pdf annotion to U+0456 і

Comment: @David Carlisle, If I didn't bore enough for you, one more remark. I tried `\DeclareTextSymbol{Ё}{X2}{65}` (`Ё` is some Cyrillic letter too), then typing `Ё` expextingly produced Æ. I would be happy if could redefine (vice versa) Æ to Ё or somewhat else seldom character. `\DeclareTextSymbol{Æ}{X2}{64}` change nothing.

Comment: The first argument of \DeclareTextSymbol should be a command like `\textendash` if you put a character there it is essentially like using that character with `\newcommand` anything that happens is accidental unplanned code as a result of lack of error checking  by the system

Comment: Well. But I tried also to redefine `\CYRAE` by different way, including `renewcommand`. Why does the behaviour of `A` remain Æ?

Comment: I don't know how often I can say this or make it more clear. `A` necessarily chooses slot 65 from the font and in an X2 encoded font that is `Æ` This is a direct font access: no macro definition will change this.

Comment: If you want an ASCII compatible cyrillic encoding use T2 not X2 that is why the two choices exist

Comment: Well, I see that I'm boring already enough. Of cource, I remember what you said that it is impossible to change slot or relation between letter and slot because of direct access to font.  Despite `\DeclareTextSymbol{Ё}{X2}{65}` works, it is not the same for latins A-Z and a-z.  It seems that Cyrillic letters uses macro (like `\CYRAE`), but for Latin ones there is direct access to font, and I cannnot change it without replacinf font (each font used in X2).
Thanks for your help, your remarrks are very useful. Sorry for my being annoying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information:

System TTF/OTF fonts have greater variety and versatility, and a Unicode font with Latin and Cyrillic in it copy-pastes OK from the PDF, but you will need an Input Method to enter the text (e.g., Ukrainian keyboard layout).

[image: uk]

Compile with lualatex.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} % has Latin, Greek, Cyrillic

\begin{document}
Ukrainian

Україна, Дніпро

\end{document}
```

---

`Polyglossia` or `Babel` might help.

`Babel` can identify character codes, so can be used to, e.g., mark erroneous keyboard layout switching.

*Polyglossia*

[image: polyglossia]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{ukrainian}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue] 
\newfontfamily\ukrainianfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
Polyglossia -- by language environment

Ukrainian


\selectlanguage{ukrainian}

Україна, Дніпро

some English text
планетна система, що включає в себе центральну зорю — Сонце, і всі природні космічні об'єкти (планети, астероїди, комети, потоки сонячного вітру тощо), які об'єднуються гравітаційною взаємодією[6]. 
-- Матеріал з Вікіпедії

\end{document}
```

*Babel*

[image: babel]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[ukrainian, english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{ukrainian}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Colour=red]{Noto Serif} 
\babelfont[ukrainian]{rm}{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{english}
Babel -- by Unicode block: note the deliberate a (not а) in системa.

Ukrainian


%\selectlanguage{ukrainian}

Україна, Дніпро

some English text
планетна системa, що включає в себе центральну зорю — Сонце, і всі природні космічні об'єкти (планети, астероїди, комети, потоки сонячного вітру тощо), які об'єднуються гравітаційною взаємодією[6]. 
-- Матеріал з Вікіпедії

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes as I said in my first comment under the question, using Unicode is a lot simpler than fighting with legacy tex-specific encodings

Answer (score 2):

cw post, so can show code, feel free to edit

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[X2]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Україна, Дніпро

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

and if I cut and paste from the pdf (from xpdf) I get Cyrillic letters not an ascii `i`

See

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0,%20%D0%94%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE

Changing to `T2A` the output looks the same but cuts and pastes with Latin `i`

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0,%20%D0%94%D0%BDi%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE

You can fix the cut and past by specifying ActualText

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\DeclareTextCommand{\cyrii}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0456}i\EndAccSupp{}}
\DeclareTextCommand{\CYRII}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0406}I\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}

Україна, Дніпро

\end{document}
```

Produces the same cut text as the X2 version.

Comment: Yes, it is Ok. However, if you add, e.g., English `I am working`, and forget to switch to T1, you obtain instead extended Cyrillic, without any error or warning.

Comment: @Spectorsky yes this is not so much an answer as  me experimenting in public:-) but I think fixing the T2A is likely to be easier than adjusting X2 not to use ascii slots

Comment: So, I'll need to type something like `U+0456` instead of each `І`. This letter is used rather offen. I thought about to fix T2A, but it seems to do much more than to check text for English output.

Comment: @Spectorsky no you don't need to change input text i just fixed the T2A definition to annotate `i` so it cuts as a Ukranian i see new update

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try it. By the way, you don't use `inputenc` - as I remember, `utf8` is default. I usually use `cp866nav` - does it work with unicode insertion?

Comment: And, by the way, how `\CYRAE` (for example) is used in order for `A` to become `Æ` in X2 encoding?

Comment: @Spectorsky it should work with any input encoding, although you should probably switch to utf-8 Not just latex but everywhere. Any code posted to this site for example is necessarily utf-8. 8-bit code pages like cp866 are very 20th century.

Comment: @Spectorsky `x2enc.def`defines `\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRAE}{X2}{65}`  so \CYRAE uses slot 65 from an X2 encoded font. But of course if you mis-use `A` that will access the same slot. I do not see any reasonable way to prevent that while using x2 encoded fonts

Comment: Sorry for my being annoying.
And if I try `\DeclareTextSymbol{something else}{X2}{65}` - why it does not redefine slot 65 to something other?

Comment: @Spectorsky you can not redefine slot 65 from TeX, you would have to make a different font  that had a different character.  (that is a new version of _every_ x2 font every size and style) You are reading the command backwards. `\DeclareTextSymbol{\CYRAE}{X2}{65}` defines `\CYRAE` so `\DeclareTextSymbol{\somethingelse}{X2}{65}`  defines `\somethingelse` to be the same as `\CYRAE` . slot65 remains whatever is in the font at that position